# Employees vs Staff

Tags: grammar

It feels more correct to say "This food was cooked by the staff of Eat Out restaurant" as opposed to "This food was cooked by the employees of Eat Out restaurant."

I cannot, however explain to an English learner why this is so. Is it just a matter of common usage? Is there a grammatical angle to it?

Comment: Please don't use code blocks for emphasis, it messes with screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of the very common phenomenon in English (and many other languages for that matter) of having two similar words coming from different origins. **[Staff](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/employee?s=t)** is a Germanic word that comes from middle English while **[employee](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/employee?s=t)** came into English from French in the 1800s.

In general they can be used interchangeably, but they do have different subtleties. **Employee** is a bit more formal and it emphasizes that the person doing the work is getting paid. In contrast, **staff** is a bit more general and simply implies that a person is a member of a group carrying out work.

In your example, both sentences work just fine. The second may seem a bit unnatural because **employee** is emphasizing that the workers are getting paid, but this is irrelevant in the context of your sentence (just a theory). For somebody learning English as a second language, both should be acceptable in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I think staff may include both employees (who get paid) and volunteers (who don't).  But both of your sentences seem fine to me.